# Datagridview add column data if it contain number

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've a `datagridview` like this:

```
------------------------
| S.N   |Data1 |  Data2|
| 1     |  -   | 10    |
| 2     |  4   | 2     |
| 3     |  2   |  -    |
| 4     |  9   |  -    |
```

I want result like this:

```
------------------------
| S.N   |Data1 |  Data2|
| 1     |  -   | 10    |
| 2     |  4   | 2     |
| 3     |  2   |  -    |
| 4     |  9   |  -    |
| total |  15  |  12   |
-----------------------
```

I've tried this:

```
Dim data1 As double = 0
Dim data2 As double = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
  data1 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value))
  data2 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))
Next
Dim rows As String() = {"Total", data1, data2}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows)
```

But it has shown an error:

[image]

Can I extract number only from `datagridview` and display `sum` of them 
and add to the last `row`?

Comment: You didn't tell what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: @LarsTech It shown an error of conversion from string to error.
watch here: -> https://imgur.com/a/zPUX7

Comment: The error message tells you whats wrong.  In your example, some cells contain a ` - ` and that cannot be converted to  double. `Val` is a bad idea too

Comment: @Plutonix It's probably the word "total" in the serial number column since presumably the OP wasn't getting the error until they added the summary row.

Comment: `Cannot convert from string '-' to type Double` sounds more like one of the `-` entries in one of the Data1 or Data2 columns.,

Comment: @Plutonix Doh!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And now I get my answer:

```
Dim data1 As double = 0
Dim data2 As double = 0
For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
  If Regex.IsMatch(DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
    data1 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value))
  End If
  If Regex.IsMatch(DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then
    data2 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value))
  End If
Next
Dim rows As String() = {"Total", data1, data2}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

This checks for nulls and ensures the data is numeric.

```
Dim data1 As double = 0
Dim data2 As double = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    If Not IsDbNull(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) AndAlso IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) Then data1 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value))
    If Not IsDbNull(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value) AndAlso IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value) Then data2 += Val(CDbl(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))

Next
Dim rows As String() = {"Total", data1, data2}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rows)
```